# TypeScript - Not able to create object of a class using new operator

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Object creation is happening without error:

```
let paginationParams: Common.Models.PaginationModel = {
    PageNumber: this.pageNumber,
    PageSize: this.pageSize,
    SearchText: this.denominationFilter,
    Ascending: true
};
```

But when trying to create that object like this:

```
let pagParams = new Common.Models.PaginationModel(
    this.pageNumber,
    this.pageSize,
    true,
    this.denominationFilter);
```

Getting error:

[image]

Comment: You'll need to share the code of `Common.Models.PaginationModel`, though it seems that if the first works that it's not a class but an interface, if that's the case then you can't use the `new` keyword

Comment: And Common.Models. Have you defined that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [snippet at TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=namespace%20Common.Models%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%09export%20interface%20IPaginationModel%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09PageNumber%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%09PageSize%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%09SearchText%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%09Ascending%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09export%20class%20PaginationModel%20implements%20IPaginationModel%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09constructor(%0D%0A%09%09%09public%20PageNumber%3A%20number%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%09%09public%20PageSize%3A%20number%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%09%09public%20SearchText%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%09%09public%20Ascending%3A%20boolean%0D%0A%09%09)%7B%7D%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20we%20use%20an%20Interface%20to%20assure%20that%20the%20type%20is%20as%20it%20should%20be%0D%0A%2F%2F%20we%20create%20object%20which%20fits%20to%20IPaginationModel%20structure%0D%0Alet%20paginationParams%3A%20Common.Models.IPaginationModel%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20PageNumber%3A%20this.pageNumber%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20PageSize%3A%20this.pageSize%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20SearchText%3A%20this.denominationFilter%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Ascending%3A%20true%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20here%20we%20use%20a%20class%0D%0A%2F%2F%20to%20call%20its%20constructor%0D%0Alet%20pagParams%20%3D%20new%20Common.Models.PaginationModel(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.pageNumber%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.pageSize%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.denominationFilter%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20true)%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%2F%2F%20and%20we%20can%20even%20use%20class%20as%20interface%20(as%20the%20first%20example)%0D%0Alet%20paginationParamsAsClassAPI%3A%20Common.Models.PaginationModel%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20PageNumber%3A%20this.pageNumber%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20PageSize%3A%20this.pageSize%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20SearchText%3A%20this.denominationFilter%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Ascending%3A%20true%0D%0A%7D%3B)

I would say, that we can think about this interface and its implementation

```
namespace Common.Models
{
    export interface IPaginationModel {
        PageNumber: number;
        PageSize: number;
        SearchText: string;
        Ascending: boolean;
    }
    export class PaginationModel implements IPaginationModel {
        constructor(
            public PageNumber: number,
            public PageSize: number,
            public SearchText: string,
            public Ascending: boolean
        ){}
    }
}
```

and then we can use it like this

```
// we use an Interface to assure that the type is as it should be
// we create object which fits to IPaginationModel structure
let paginationParams: Common.Models.IPaginationModel = {
    PageNumber: this.pageNumber,
    PageSize: this.pageSize,
    SearchText: this.denominationFilter,
    Ascending: true
};

// here we use a class
// to call its constructor
let pagParams = new Common.Models.PaginationModel(
    this.pageNumber,
    this.pageSize,
    this.denominationFilter,
    true);

// and we can even use class as interface (as the first example)
let paginationParamsAsClassAPI: Common.Models.PaginationModel = {
    PageNumber: this.pageNumber,
    PageSize: this.pageSize,
    SearchText: this.denominationFilter,
    Ascending: true
};
```

So, we can use interface and class as a type, while building plain JS object *(first and third example)* or we can use the class constructor to build such instance.

Check it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=namespace%20Common.Models%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%09export%20interface%20IPaginationModel%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09PageNumber%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%09PageSize%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%09SearchText%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%09Ascending%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09export%20class%20PaginationModel%20implements%20IPaginationModel%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09constructor(%0D%0A%09%09%09public%20PageNumber%3A%20number%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%09%09public%20PageSize%3A%20number%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%09%09public%20SearchText%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%09%09public%20Ascending%3A%20boolean%0D%0A%09%09)%7B%7D%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20we%20use%20an%20Interface%20to%20assure%20that%20the%20type%20is%20as%20it%20should%20be%0D%0A%2F%2F%20we%20create%20object%20which%20fits%20to%20IPaginationModel%20structure%0D%0Alet%20paginationParams%3A%20Common.Models.IPaginationModel%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20PageNumber%3A%20this.pageNumber%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20PageSize%3A%20this.pageSize%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20SearchText%3A%20this.denominationFilter%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Ascending%3A%20true%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20here%20we%20use%20a%20class%0D%0A%2F%2F%20to%20call%20its%20constructor%0D%0Alet%20pagParams%20%3D%20new%20Common.Models.PaginationModel(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.pageNumber%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.pageSize%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.denominationFilter%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20true)%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%2F%2F%20and%20we%20can%20even%20use%20class%20as%20interface%20(as%20the%20first%20example)%0D%0Alet%20paginationParamsAsClassAPI%3A%20Common.Models.PaginationModel%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20PageNumber%3A%20this.pageNumber%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20PageSize%3A%20this.pageSize%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20SearchText%3A%20this.denominationFilter%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Ascending%3A%20true%0D%0A%7D%3B)